# GuiceFXMLLoader: load() method not giving the desired output

Tags: java, controller, javafx, guice, fxml

I have a following method:

```
public Object getCurrentController (URL path) {

GuiceFXMLLoader loader;

Result result = loader.load(path);

Object controller = result.getController();

return controller;
}
```

This method is supposed to return the controller object corresponding to the `.fxml` file whose path is given in the argument `path`.

It is returning null instead of returning the correct controller object.

Problem is happening while getting the `result` from `loader.load(path);` only.

Will you please tell me why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: This code will not work as you have not initialised 'loader' anywhere and consequently loader.load(path) will throw a NullPointerException. I'm not clear from your question if that is what actually happening or if you've copied some erroneous code into your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Actually, I got rid of that issue (forgot to post solution over here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got rid of the problem.

The thing was I did not have following:

```
fx:controller="com.....IExampleController"
```

in the .fxml file.

I added it and now it is giving me the desired output.